# Is there any way to make ProgressBarStyle.Marquee to move from side to side?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
pBarTotalProgress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
pBarTotalProgress.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
```

Now it's moving from left to right over and over again.
I wonder if there is a way to make it move from left to right then from right to left ?

Comment: Yes. Write a new version of the control yourself. The built-in version doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to roll your own.

The "Marquee" progress bar, which currently resumes left-to-right after hitting the end, is the default OS behavior.